# Hyper V over VPN?

Tags: hyper-v

We are in process of trying to plan our Hyper V installation in 2 locations. We wanted to get some feedback on how we can accomplish a HA Hyper V server with shared storage at HQ and a Hyper V server at a remote site connected by a VPN tunnel?

We are just looking for ideas on how to implement remote sites using Hyper V. We currently use Citrix, but with the move going towards Hyper V, just trying to get some ideas or if someone knows a good site/book explaining this process.

Thanks for everyones help again.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, your choice is a Hyper-Converged scenario (Hypervisor and SAN are on the same hosts). From my experience, without improving the network you won't get the High Availability. But you can ask [HP](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/data-storage/free-vsa.html) or [StarWind](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san) engineers if is it possible. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

While this may be technically possible, it's a bad, bad idea. Storage systems require consistent, low-latency connections. That is not going to be possible over a VPN connection. If you want HA, you'll likely need to investigate volume replication between sites with VM failover.

Comment: And EEAA means low latency when he says so. Modern storage measures in microseconds. Old storage (discs) in milliseconds. You are challenged to get this over a local network (SAN) with any sort of tunnel - running it between locations is not going to work, period.

Comment: @TomTom you're confusing seek times and typical response times. These are DIFFERENT things! Completely. Disk-based SAN can handle 5 ms round trip just fine and some NVMf can have 30 seconds of lag under heavy load. P.S. It's me who upvoted you, sorry about that ;(